# jquery function has string parameter to access object

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a shoe conversion function...here's the idea:

- I have two arrays, one for US shoe size and another for EU shoe size
- I have a conversion function that does takes in the US shoe size and the country to convert to.
- The function looks for the shoe size passed in to find the its index in the US array.
- Next the function takes the index found to access the item in the same index position in the EU array.

  ```
  //Shoe size arrays
  var US = [3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];
  var EU = [35, 35.5, 36, 37, 37.5, 38, 38.5, 39, 40, 41, 41.5, 42, 42.5, 43, 44, 44.5, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50];


  var currentsize = 6.5;
  var countrycode = 'EU';
  convertShoeSize(currentsize, countrycode);

  function convertShoeSize(size, converto){
      var sizelocation = $.inArray(size, US);
      console.log(size + ' is at index ' + sizelocation);
      console.log('going to ' + converto);
      console.log(typeof(converto));
      console.log(typeof(EU));
      //this is where I want the parameter to access the array
      //with the same name, so the EU array created at top
      var converted = converto[sizelocation];
      console.log(converted);

  }
  ```

The parameter countrycode is coming in as a string, I want to use that string to match my array object with the same name (commented above). Get the result of *undefined*.

If I use:

`var converted = converto[1]`

I get U, likewise if I ask for index 0 I get E. So I know I'm not accessing the EU array, I'm just looking at the string.

How can I take a string parameter to match an object with an identical name.

This is really basic I'm sure but I've not been able to find an answer over that last few hours anywhere online. Imagine I'm using incorrect terms in my search. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of array's use it as a object. Your problem will be solved

Change it to

```
var shoe_sizes = {
    "US" : [3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10,
            10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    "EU" : [35, 35.5, 36, 37, 37.5, 38, 38.5, 39, 40, 41, 41.5, 42, 
            42.5, 43, 44, 44.5, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50] 
};
var currentsize = 6.5;
var countrycode = 'US',
    convertTo = 'EU';
convertShoeSize(currentsize, convertTo);

function convertShoeSize(size, converto) {
    var sizelocation;
    // Assign the value and check if the index is not -1
    if ((sizelocation = $.inArray(size, shoe_sizes[countrycode])) 
                      && sizelocation !== -1) {
        console.log(size + ' is at index ' + sizelocation);
        console.log('going to ' + converto);
        console.log(typeof (converto));        console.log(typeof (EU));
        //this is where I want the parameter to access the array
        //with the same name, so the EU array created at top
        var converted = shoe_sizes[converto][sizelocation];
        console.log(converted);
    }
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/mSD8V/)**

Comment: +1 using an object is a good idea. I think naming the variable country may be off though. Perhaps 'shoe_sizes' would be a better name?

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks so much!! I hadn't thought of using an object.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the array to window['EU'], and access it in you function with window[convertto].

Comment: This may or may not work depending on the scope of the OP's code. Hopefully it's namespaced and those are not global variables, in which case this answer won't work.